# Uninstalling Visual Studio 2010 components

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've asked this question over in the SuperUser site, but thought I'd ask it here to due to the expertise of so many SO users.
I've recently installed Visual Studio 2010 Professional (for a university project). We have to design a dummy interface for a system modelling scrum management (i.e. to allow users to create and plan agile projects). We don't need to do any real coding, just design the interface - however, if we choose, we can add in a little C# (we've only programmed in Java and we are at an elementary level, which is why there is so little coding).

I installed the Professional edition of Visual Studio, asking for just the C# package. The program ended up installing all of the following:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Framework  
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Project  
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects  
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects (x64)  
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Transact-SQL Language Service  
Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 ENU  
Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 x64 ENU  
Microsoft SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard 1.4  
Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types  
Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types (x64)  
Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 SP1 (x64)  
Microsoft Sync Framework SDK v1.0 SP1  
Microsoft Sync Framework Services v1.0 SP1 (x64)   
Microsoft Sync Services for ADO.NET v2.0 SP1 (x64)  
Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Object Model - ENU  
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.4148  
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.4974  
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x64 Runtime - 10.0.30319  
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Runtime - 10.0.30319  
Microsoft Visual Studio ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools  
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU  
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x64)   
Microsoft Visual Studio Macro Tools
```

I've heard that I can't get rid of the SQL Server Compact as it is needed for Visual Studio to run. I'm also aware that the Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU IS the actual program. However, after these, bearing in mind my needs for the program, what can I uninstall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question. Someone actually left a comment on what to do, but they seem to have deleted it. I don't remember who it was - apologies to them.

I was using Visual Studio 2010 Professional as we got it free through our university's connection to the Microsoft Developer Network.

However, a free version of this software without a lot of what was unnecessary for me exists - Visual Studio Express. It can be found at:
http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products

Comment: maybe the content of your link changed but it doesn't answer the question: _what can I uninstall?_